# Regular expression in Swift to validate Cardholder name

Tags: swift, regex, nsregularexpression

I am looking for a regular expression to use in **Swift** to validate cardholder name for a credit card. I am looking for a regEx which:

- Has minimum 2 and maximum of 26 characters
- Accept dashes (`-`) and apostrophes (`'`) only and no other special character
- Capital and small alphabets and no numbers.
- Should not start with a blank space.

I was using this

```
"^[^-\\s][\\p{L}\\-'\\s]{2,26}$"
```

but it only accepts dash (`-`) no apostrophe (`'`)

Comment: Highly recommend using regex101.com to test out and refine your regular expression. https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try with this regex

```
(?<! )[-a-zA-Z' ]{2,26}
```

see here

> https://regex101.com/r/0UVvR1/1

Comment: This regex is not validating John Mc'Kenzie. It's not taking spaces between the first name last name as well.

Comment: *I am looking for a regEx which - - Has minimum 2 and maximum 26 characters - Accept dashes (-) and apostrophes (') only and no other special character - Capital and small alphabets and no numbers. - Should not start with a blank space*>>> you didn't ask for that... try now

Comment: Card holder name may also contain dots (.) like John F. Kennedy or Mrs. Robinson

Comment: OP explicitly asks for this `Has minimum 2 and maximum 26 characters - Accept dashes (-) and apostrophes (') only and no other special character`; so, she/he didn't want dots to be a valid char; but, sure, you can add dots too.

Answer (score 3):

Guessing from your description, this is what you are looking for:

```
^[\p{L}'-][\p{L}' -]{1,25}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/493eLF/1)

A few remarks:

- you propbably do not want to allow all possible white-space chars `[\r\n\t\f\v ]` but just spaces.
- you  have to adjust the allowed lenght of the second string if you add a 1st group that does not include space and dash (since that group contributs an additional character).
- with `\p{L}` you allow any kind of letter from any language (which is good); otherwise use `[a-zA-z]` if just want to allow the regular (ASCII) alphabet.

PS: Do not forget to escape the pattern properly: `"^[\\p{L}'][\\p{L}' -]{1,25}$"`