# How to validate a name(John D'Largy) in iOS Swift4.2?

Tags: ios, regex, swift4.2

i tried all possibilities in stack-overflow ([link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385701/regular-expression-for-first-and-last-name/2385811), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49992102/regular-expression-in-swift-to-validate-cardholder-name)) answers no use for me.

I am using following Regex to validate a first name. In online case ([OnlineRegex](https://regex101.com/)) it is working fine but when i implemented in mobile it is not working.

Please help me

```
func isValidName() -> Bool {
    let RegEx = "^[a-zA-Z]+(([\\'\\,\\.\\-\\ ][a-zA-Z ])?[a-zA-Z]*)*$"
    let Test = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", RegEx)
    return Test.evaluate(with: self)
}
```

i am calling above function as

```
let str = "John D'Largy"
        if str.isValidName(){
            print("Valid")
        }else{ print("Not valid")}
```

**Output** :  "Valid"

Same function i am calling to validate my first text feild i am getting "Not valid"

```
if firstNameTxt.text.isValidName(){
            print("Valid")
        }else{ print("Not valid")}
```

i entered same text in mobile keyword

**OutPut**: "Not valid"

Did i missing something? or Should i have to change regex value?. 
Any suggestions.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try `[a-zA-Z]+(?:[',.\\s-][a-zA-Z]+)*`. You do not need `^` and `$`

Comment: @wiktor Stribiżew i used your line it is getting valid when i given text as string. When i'm entering the same text in mobile in textfeild it is showing not valid

Comment: It is because you should only use this regex for final string validation.  To make it work with partial string input add `?` after `[',.\\s-]`.

Comment: i tried Both( 1). [a-zA-Z]+(?:[',.\\s-]?[a-zA-Z]+)*   2). [a-zA-Z]+(?:[',.\\s-][a-zA-Z]+)* ) no use

Comment: I think the regex should allow an empty string. Try `(?:[a-zA-Z]+(?:[',.\\s-]?[a-zA-Z]+)*)?`

Comment: Thank you for your support but still not working.

Comment: Try `(?:[a-zA-Z]+(?:['‘’,.\\s-]?[a-zA-Z]+)*)?` (add the curly quotes). Or use the previous regex and set `textfield.smartQuotesType` property to `no`

Comment: Awesome  reply thank you it's working fine
After adding this (?:[a-zA-Z]+(?:['‘’,.\\s-]?[a-zA-Z]+)*)?

Comment: I posted an answer below with explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:[a-zA-Z]+(?:['‘’,.\\s-]?[a-zA-Z]+)*)?
```

The code you have already requires the full string match and you need no explicit anchors like `^` / `\A` and `$` / `\z`.

Also, since the single quotation marks are automatically converted to curly quotes, you should either add them to the regex or [turn off the behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44932863/ios-11-disable-smart-quotes).

One of the most important things about thi regex is that it should be able to match *partially* correct string, thus all of the parts are optional (i.e. they can match 0 chars). It is wrapped with an optional non-capturing group (`(?:...)?`) that matches 1 or 0 occurrences.

**Regex details**

- `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1 or more letters
- `(?:` - start of the inner non-capturing group:

  - `['‘’,.\\s-]?` - 1 or 0 whitespaces, single quotes, hyphens
  - `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1+ letters
- `)*` - 0 or more repetitions.

Note: to match any Unbicode letter, use `\\p{L}` instead of `[a-zA-Z]`.

**Graph**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> See, I tried your code in the playground and changed the syntax a bit but not the logic

[image]

> Below is the code snippet, try running that in your playground

```
    func isValidName(str: String) -> Bool {
       let RegEx = "^[a-zA-Z]+(([\\'\\,\\.\\-\\ ][a-zA-Z ])?[a-zA-Z]*)*$"
       let Test = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", RegEx)
       return Test.evaluate(with: str)
    }

    func check(){
       let str = "John D'Largy"

       if isValidName(str: str){
           print("Valid")
       }else{
           print("Not valid")
       }
    }

check()
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Have your tried the way I showed? It is working fine in swift 4 and upwards.

Comment: i tried your code it is working when static data given. When user is typing the name it is getting "Invalid"